# Explaining recurring crash in postgresql deployment

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, django

I'm having trouble with unexpected system crashes emanating from a postgresql deployment on a moderately busy production server (Django 1.8 app deployed on DO droplet with a `gunicorn` application server and `nginx` reverse proxy).

I'm an accidental DBA and need an expert's opinion on piecing together what's going on. I have no clue right now; I'll provide various log data below:

The whole app crashes - new relic ends up showing the following error:

`django.db.utils:OperationalError: ERROR: no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)`

Full stack trace being:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 26, in _handle_and_close_when_done
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 155, in handle
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 56, in handle
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 160, in handle_request
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 114, in handle_request
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 704, in __iter__
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 1080, in __call__
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 108, in get_response
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 228, in wrapper
File "/home/ubuntu/app/mproject/middleware/mycustommiddleware.py", line 6, in process_request
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 225, in inner
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 376, in _setup
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 22, in <lambda>
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 10, in get_user
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 174, in get_user
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 93, in get_user
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 328, in get
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in __len__
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 838, in execute_sql
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 164, in cursor
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/hooks/database_dbapi2.py", line 102, in __call__
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycogreen/gevent.py", line 32, in gevent_wait_callback
```

New relic also shows a huge spike in `Postgres set`:

[image]

Postgresql slow log shows exorbitant COMMIT durations like so:

```
2020-05-15 01:22:47.474 UTC [10722] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 280668.902 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-05-15 01:22:47.474 UTC [11536] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 49251.277 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-05-15 01:22:47.474 UTC [10719] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 281609.394 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-05-15 01:22:47.474 UTC [10719] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
2020-05-15 01:22:47.474 UTC [10719] ubuntu@myapp FATAL:  connection to client lost
2020-05-15 01:22:47.475 UTC [10672] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 285371.872 ms  statement: COMMIT
```

Digital ocean's dashboard shows a spike in `Load Average` and `Disk IO` (but `CPU`, `memory usage` and `disk usage` remain low).

[image]

The snapshot stats at the time of that `Load Average` spike are:

[image]

`syslog` has myriad instances of the following error log:

```
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]: error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]: [2020-05-15 01:22:46 +0000] [10874] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 66, in handle
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 56, in handle
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 160, in handle_request
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     addr)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 129, in handle_request
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 114, in handle_request
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     for item in respiter:
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 704, in __iter__
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     for item in self.generator:
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 1080, in __call__
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.start_response)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     response = self.get_response(request)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 448, in wrapper
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     return _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 441, in _wrapped
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     return wrapped(request, resolver, exc_info)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 256, in handle_uncaught_exception
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     'request': request
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1193, in error
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1286, in _log
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.handle(record)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1296, in handle
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.callHandlers(record)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1336, in callHandlers
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     hdlr.handle(record)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 759, in handle
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.emit(record)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 129, in emit
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 132, in send_mail
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 110, in literal_wrapper
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 98, in mail_admins
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 110, in literal_wrapper
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     new_conn_created = self.open()
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 96, in create_connection
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     sock.connect(sa)
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket2.py", line 244, in connect
May 15 01:22:46 main-app gunicorn[10779]:     raise error(err, strerror(err))
```

Some lines from `vmtstat 1`:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 4698028 280600 16692992    0    0     0    14    0    0 13  1 87  0  0
 3  0      0 4697204 280600 16693016    0    0     0    24 8294 8111 12  0 88  0  0
 3  0      0 4698148 280600 16693044    0    0     0   204 8533 9047 15  0 85  0  0
 4  0      0 4697628 280600 16693092    0    0     0    76 8695 8775 17  1 83  0  0
 3  0      0 4697288 280600 16693140    0    0     8    16 9578 9720 19  1 80  0  0
 3  0      0 4695768 280600 16693200    0    0     0   152 8594 8073 16  1 83  0  0
 6  0      0 4686044 280600 16693272    0    0     0    32 7998 7706 12  1 87  0  0
 5  0      0 4681876 280600 16693308    0    0     0   224 9130 8810 14  1 85  0  0
```

That's pretty much all I have. I can't piece together what could be going on at all. It's happening almost once a day now. Can an expert shed some light on this? Thanks in advance!

---

Note: in case warranted, `SELECT version();` yields:

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.16 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.16-1.pgdg16.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
```

Comment: What's the number of max connection on postgres? You can find in postgresql.conf file

Comment: "*no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)*" indicates a problem in your code that connections to the database are not properly closed.

Comment: @AG: thanks for getting in touch, I appreciate it. `max_connections = 400` is set in postgresql.conf. I also use `pgbouncer` in this set up (in case it matters). That's set to `transaction pooling`, `max_client_conn = 250` and `default_pool_size = 30`. Any ideas?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: connections not properly closed (hmm). In case it matters, I also use `pgbouncer`. That's set to `transaction pooling`. The reason is really eluding me, especially because this whole thing has been running stably for around a year (and no tinkering has taken place).Any next steps you can define that would help me get closer to the truth?

Comment: @jjanes: `vmstat` lines are after-the-fact unfortunately. I'll update them as soon as the event re-occurs. Meanwhile, check out the screenshot I just attached above the "popup". Hopefully that'll show you the whole picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4.6 minute COMMIT is nearly definitive that your IO system is either grossly inadequate, or just completely hosed.  Which would explain all the rest of the problems.  If connections can't commit, they won't ordinarily be closed, so they build up.  Eventually you get "ERROR: no more connections allowed".  If a client gives up on waiting for a commit response and drops the connection, you might get 'FATAL:  connection to client lost on' the server.  Note there is no PostgreSQL "crash" here, it is still running and serving connections (slowly) until max_connections is exceeded, at which point it is still serving existing connections.

There are things other than fsync which a COMMIT does, and occasionally but rarely those thing can cause problems.  So to be more definitive, you can sample pg_stat_activity and see what wait_event and wait_event_type for the commits are during these episodes.  If wait_event is 'WALWriteLock' or 'WALSync' that is pretty definitive.

If you paid for a storage system with a service level > 'gerbil', I would say this falls squarely in Digital Ocean's hands.

Answer (score 2):

The long commit times indicate that I/O on the database server is seriously overloaded. The machine seems to come to a crawl, so that it cannot respond to connection requests in a timely fashion any more.

Examine the database workload and see what causes the overload.

Comment: So if some postgres statements were taking too long - they would have showed up in the slow log too right? Nothing in my slow log compares to the kind of time those slow COMMITs took (e.g. `280 seconds` and thereabout). Could you guide me how to delve deeper into this?

Comment: You cannot, because it is a hosted machine. Can you request support?

Comment: Well it's a virtual machine, and I can log into its terminal. Wouldn't that enable me to probe around?

Comment: Ah, that's good. Run `vmstat 1` and check the `wa` column (next to last). If that is high, you have a proof for I/O overload.

Comment: I added the output of `vmstat 1` at the end of the question. `wa` is looking elevated right now. I'm guessing these values would have given an even more accurate picture had I looked them up at the time of the crash?

Comment: @jjanes: well digital ocean describes it as `Block storage volumes are network-based block devices that provide additional data storage for Droplets. You can move them between Droplets and resize them at any time.` So I guess 'yes' it's virtualized storage? What's the implication here?

Comment: Maybe that virtualized system is seizing up, leading to 5 minute long COMMIT due to 5 minute long virtualized fsyncs on the WAL files, and that in turn causes all the other problems.  I can't predict how such a thing would show up in  vmstat, or any of the charts you have displayed.

Comment: No, `wa` looks fine; it is 0 throughout (the output is ill-aligned). Then, as Jeff says, it is probably something related to virtualization. Or your storage has intermittent problems.